# Broken pyreadline in IPython in MSYS2

Tags: ipython, python-3.5, msys2

I have a MSYS2 system, where I've installed python3.5 together with all of its dependencies. Furthermore, I've installed ipython using pip3.5 along with pyreadline 2.1. When I start ipython I get this prompt:
[image: completion broken]

It is broken (as you can see on space between the brackets, and it does not complete any commmands - instead it inserts tabs. Anyone that have a clue what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pyreadline is broken on windows, IPython will move away from readline on the next version (5.0). This should fix things.

Comment: Oh, that's annoying